# Kendo UI grid (javascript) - how to populate cells via call to function?

Tags: kendo-ui

My dataSource data object is a collection of items (500+):

```
{
   var oftype; // can be 1, 2, 3 etc.
   var value; // string value of variable length
}
```

when displaying it in Kendo grid I am showing "value" but, instead of "oftype" values of 1,2,3 etc I'd like to display description of "oftype". I have a function 
getDescription (oftype); that returns a string.

**Question**: 
   how can I define kendo grid so it uses function getDescription to populate column "oftype"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) in the column, like:

```
template: "#: getDescription(oftype) #"
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ejIcO)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! My vote is not yet registered as legit (need to get approval, I guess), but I honestly tried. :). Not only you helped with the question, but I found reference to "template " in Kendo docs and it is very helpful as well.

Comment: @MichaelEstrinOne nice to hear that! You need at least 15 rep points to cast a upvote.